# How to handle failed Optional Binding

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I am trying to create a new URL data type from a string, which returns an optional. When I try optional binding, the indented code never gets executed.

How do I trap the error or reason why the optional binding fails?

```
let newString = "http://somehost:1337/parse/classes/CompEntry?where={\"CompID\":{\"__type\":\"Pointer\",\"className\":\"Competition\",\"objectId\":\"CXy40U65Z9\"}}"
if let url = URL(string: newString) {
    print("here") // NEVER GETS EXECUTED
}
```

Is it because of the escaped " characters in the string?

Comment: Is your question about  “how to handle failed optional binding” or about “how to escape an URL string correctly”?

Comment: That is not how to make a URL.  Use URLComponents. Never call URL(string:) in real code!

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, @matt. Trying to use the queryItemToken method, but I still have the same problem with the escaped characters within a String. I need to provide this JSON format for Parse Platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add else to the IF control flow

```
let newString = "http://somehost:1337/parse/classes/CompEntry?where={\"CompID\":{\"__type\":\"Pointer\",\"className\":\"Competition\",\"objectId\":\"CXy40U65Z9\"}}"
    if let url = URL(string: newString) {
        print("here") // NEVER GETS EXECUTED
    } else {
        print("here") // EXECUTED when optional binding fails
    }
```

**Updated:**
Author expected an error

URL initializer doesn't throws an error in case of not being able to parse a given string

> This initializer returns nil if the string doesn’t represent a valid
> URL. For example, an empty string or one containing characters that
> are illegal in a URL produces nil. [source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/3126806-init)

Comment: Yes, I added similar code to verify that the `if let` statement failed. I just dont know why or how to troubleshoot. There doesn't seem to be an `error` object...

Comment: Thanks @Alexander-ReinstateMonica - that does answer. From matt's comment in response to the original post, I am also investigating URLComponents

Answer (score 0):

You can create the url from the string like below:

```
let newString = "http://somehost:1337/parse/classes/CompEntry"
if let url = URL(string: newString) {
     print("here")
}
```

And then create a params dictionary like :

```
 params = ["CompID": ["__type": "Pointer", "className": "Competition", "objectId": "CXy40U65Z9"]]
```

And then send these params in httpBody of the URLRequest.